Exception Value: time data '2019-01-02' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
Me salta este error porque algunos navegadores lo tienen en inglés de EEUU y por ello tienen otro formato.
yo tengo en el modelo.py
fecha_compra = DateTimeFractionField3(verbose_name=_('trade date'))

y en el admin.py
@admin.register(Coches)
class CochesAdmin(VehiculosBaseAdmin, ReadOnlyModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [('fecha_compra', DateRangeFilter),]

    def fecha_compra(self, obj): # no funciona
        return timezone.localtime(obj.fecha_compra).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

¿Cómo debería hacerlo?
Muchas gracias por adelantado

Tienes que transformarlo a tipo datetime y despues lo conviertes a str.

Al final tuve que refactorizar la propia función de django

No se nada de django, pero se me ocurren ideas de como se puede abordar el tema con fechas.
Tampoco soy experto en tratar con la comunidad internacional, pero...
Supongo que estás tratando de tomar una fecha ingresada por el cliente en forma de texto, y convertirla al formato %d/%m/%Y.
Por que la prueba y error no sería el mejor camino
Teniendo la lista de formatos posibles en los que puede venir una fecha, se puede probar cada posible formato hasta dar con uno que pueda usarse para parsear la fecha (no necesariamente es el formato correcto, ver más abajo).
Aunque podés hacerlo vos mismo, me parece, que la función del modulo de terceros dateutils dateutils.parser.parse hace eso mismo.
Falla para combinaciones como %Y-%m-%d y %Y-%d-%m. Ya que, por ejemplo, la fecha "2020-12-10" es valida para ambos formatos, solo que en el primero el mes será 12, y en el segundo será 10.
No conozco un mejor enfoque para evadir el problema antes mencionado sin cambiar la tecnica, ya que ni siquiera un ser humano tendría información suficiente para reconocer cual de los dos formatos es el correcto.
¿Y si usamos el formato default del dispositivo del cliente?
Mi recomendación, si querés ser flexible con el formato de fecha y no usar uno especifico, es que busques (o esperes otra respuesta que te diga) como conocer el formato en que la fecha es ingresada. Quizá puedas conocer el timezone establecido en el dispositivo usando javascript y enviar la fecha ya parseada desde dicho lenguaje. Se me ocurre, por ejemplo...

Que asumas que la fecha va a ser ingresada en la timezone que tiene puesta el usuario en su dispositivo.

O un camino más sencillo, un campo o combobox que permita seleccionar o escribir el formato de fecha, que puede tener por default el formato del timezone del dispositivo.


La desventaja, es que la primera idea puede ser restrictiva, y la segunda un poco molesta.
¿Y si... ingresamos la fecha de otra forma?
Para mi, esta es la mejor idea.
Podrías usar un widget similar a un calendario para permitir al usuario ingresar la fecha. Esto es independiente de cual sería el formato en el que el usuario escribiría la fecha.
Aquí dejo una pagina y una captura de a lo que me refiero.

Ni siquiera tenes que programarlo por tu cuenta, ya que esta pagina justamente ofrece ese mismisimo widget.
